# PerfMon Server Agent without listener

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, apm

[PerfMon Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=PerfMon) is working fine with JMeter's Listener `jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector`.

But can it act as a standalone application performance monitoring (APM) agent?

I saw that I can connect and request specific metrics

> Server Agent uses simple plain-text protocol, anyone can use agent's capabilities implementing client, based on kg.apc.perfmon.client.Transport interface. If anyone's interested, start the topic on the support forums and I'll describe how to connect third-party client app to agent.

But can I start PerfMon Server when my application is started and save metrics "always" (until application is down) without any listener?

Also can I display the results in a tool other than `jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into [Server Agent documentation](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#using-server-agent-with-other-applications) you'll learn that it can be used by any application capable of sending plain text message over TCP or UDP protocol (i.e. [telnet](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-telnet-2626026) or [netcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)) so you can trigger metrics collection by just sending metric name to the running Server Agent.

With regards to starting PerfMon when your application is started - Server Agent is normal pure Java application so the approach will vary depending on operating system you're using and the nature of your application. Most likely you will need to come up with a shell script which starts both.

For the moment you won't be able to use Server Agent without a "client" - an application which will request metrics from it over TCP or UDP. So if you don't plan to use JMeter you will need to come up with a TCP or UDP client solution which will periodically query the Server Agent for metrics. The output will be normal CSV file which can be visualised using any tool ([Libre Office Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/), whatever)

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)